# Tallying dates and times in excel

Tags: excel, date, time

Is there an easy way to tally a column formatted as follows: "5/24/2013  5:48:00 PM"

What I want to do is have it tally by day of week and an hour time block, the end result I'm looking for would look like the following:

```
                  Sunday  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Saturday
    1:00-2:00AM   10      2       8        7          3         12      15
    2:00-3:00AM   5       4       7        7          9         11      18
```

et cetera. This is an extremely large data set so avoiding doing this by hand would be amazing. I apologize if this is a terrible question, I tried searching though other people's questions to no avail.

Comment: Did you try a PivotTable?

Comment: Sorry, I am definitely a beginner, I just tried using a PivotTable but I don't see how to turn that information into totals by day and hour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing the details, I would try to use a PivotTable.

There is the ability to group by dates; see [this page](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/17/group-dates-in-pivot-tables/) for details (including a fancy animation).

Some additional searching should turn up a lot of resources on PivotTables; they are very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assign a number to the rows/columns and then use sumif().

Answer (score 0):

I would create add two columns: one with `=Hour(A2)`, other with `=WeekDay(A2)` (example for row 2, assuming dates are on column A).

Then, use PivotTable on all data.

Regard formats: WeekDay must be formated as `ddd` or `dddd` and Hour as numeric.

Comment: For some reason when I move it into a pivot table I am losing about 30 of the 250 entries/rows. Anyone have any idea as to why?

Comment: Are you selecting all data to pivot? Any filters active?